# Merge screen data

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am working on a project that uses Google Analytics. Since the project was handled by other developers before me, I would like to clean up the naming convention of the Screens for Google Analytics tracking. If I change for example a screen's name from "Welcome Screen_iOS" to "Welcome - iOS", is it possible to merge the data of the two screen names in Analytics Dashboard so that the previous data from Welcome Screen_iOS will be added to the new count of the Welcome - iOS screen name.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics does not reprocess historical data, so that's a no (i.e. you cannot change the already recorded data to match the new name). It is difficult to find a good reference for this as Google documents the things they do rather than the things they do not do.

However if you want to consolidate screen names just for your users and do not mind that GA uses the old screen name you can use a [search and replace filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en) (in the view settings) on the screen name field . This will for the purpose of tracking replace the new name with the old name but will not affect your users experience. You need to create and adapt filters every time you change a screen name so you have to be sure that this is worth the trouble.